Frida - No Backtrace
I am trying to do some reverse engeniring of an android app. For that, I want to get the same stacktrace as what I'm seeing online to be able to follow tutorials etc... Basically when I run frida on my app, it crashes because it has some anti tampering/anti root/anti hook measures (which is expected).
When it crashes, I get a stacktrace like :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application [snip...]
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Native Method)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
Caused by: my.app.MessageGuardException_[snip...] DP: 751
etc....

I'm seeing other people getting more info on the crash. You can see the backtrace at the end indicating the library where it crashes:
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfa929095 in tid 8875 (re.pwnme), pid 8849 (re.pwnme)
F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/taimen/taimen:9/PQ3A.190801.002/5670241:user/release-keys'
F DEBUG   : Revision: 'rev_10'
F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
F DEBUG   : pid: 8849, tid: 8875, name: re.pwnme  >>> com.google.android.gms <<<
F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfa929095
F DEBUG   :     x0  0000007f041f6610  x1  0000007f2565c800  x2  0000007f25600000  x3  000000000000001d
F DEBUG   :     x4  000000000000005c  x5  0000000000000001  x6  0000000000000001  x7  0000000000000000
F DEBUG   :     x8  0000007f041f6610  x9  0000007f041f6600  x10 00000000fa929095  x11 00000000000035b2
F DEBUG   :     x12 00000000e34d79ac  x13 00000000fffffff7  x14 00000000a139577d  x15 0000000000000001
F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007fa66af220  x17 0000007fa65e3608  x18 0000000000000000  x19 0000007f041f6680
F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000000000000000  x22 0000229100002291  x23 0000000000000000
F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007f041ff570  x25 0000007f04102000  x26 0000007fab1ad5e0  x27 0000007f0421a690
F DEBUG   :     x28 0000007f04209080  x29 0000007f041ff490
F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007f041f65f0  lr  0000007f0423de04  pc  0000007f0423f980
F DEBUG   :
F DEBUG   : backtrace:
F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000003f980  /data/app/re.pwnme-7O3ynhSmMsg2_E5_uqbQxQ==/lib/arm64/libnative-lib.so

I was expecting to get the error format from Frida specifying a backtrace and library like above. I'm not getting it.
I tried to explore frida man page but what I tried didn't help unfortunately.
Do you have an idea why i'm not getting the same stacktrace format ? I was thinking maybe it's because i'm running android x86 and not ARM like the others. Could that be it ?

The first is a simple Java exception, the second a crash on native level. To understand the Java exception is thrown decompile it and check where it is thrown. In general I recommend not using emulators with Frida. Use a rooted physical device.

Are you sure that the "anti tampering/anti root/anti hook measures" in your app are exactly identical to the used in your tutorial? Not every anti hook system works identical, and even different versions of the same anti-hooking product can result in different results (thus crashes).

I tried to use a physical device (a51 android 13 OEM locked) and root it but was unable to. I can't find a way to unlock OEM.

You might be seeing different stacktraces because of using Android x86 instead of ARM. Most apps are optimized for ARM, so try switching to an ARM-based emulator in Android Studio.
Steps:

Open AVD Manager in Android Studio.
Create a new Virtual Device with an ARM-based system image (arm64-v8a).
Start the emulator and run your Frida script again.

Let me know if that works!

Thanks for you answer. I already tried to spawn an ARM VM with AVD but the VM won't even start.

@JiaMingWang what's the issue?

Maybe the application uses syscall to quit,you need to trace syscall or hook quit call in libc.so like exit() and exit_group(). if the application uses libc.so's function,you can trace it use
console.log('CCCryptorCreate called from:\n' +
Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE).map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).join('\n') + '\n');

if the application uses syscall you can use strace which you can find in github
